# Linear moment inequality for layman

Tags: intuition, moments, identifiability

Can someone please explain [Manski](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387004549)'s approach to Partial Identification of Probability Distributions in very basic terms? I have gone through a lot of stuff but failed to find an intuitive explanation. I also don't understand how this relates to the Linear Moment Inequality Framework.